# Replace gradient colours if eg ie9 detected or gradient feature not possible

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons that have a gradient on them but i need my website to be ie9 friendly and the buttons just appear white inside. How do I write an alternative colour into my code to fall back on if the gradient fails?

```
background: linear-gradient(#bed738, #61bc4b);
border: 1px solid #80af37;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the solid color property before the gradient. Browsers that don't understand the gradient will ignore it and use the previous property:

```
background: red;
background: linear-gradient(#bed738, #61bc4b);
```